# Lliferay script console: "No such property: Packages for class: Script1"

Tags: groovy, liferay

I am trying to use the Liferay script console in "Server administration", but I get this error:

```
"No such property: Packages for class: Script1"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to run JavaScript code in a Groovy intepreter.

What probably happened is that you selected "Groovy" and tried executing the sample hello world code, but this code is for JavaScript, and selecting the "Groovy" interpreter in the dropdown list does not replace it with any Groovy-compatible sample.

Solution: Either switch the interpreter back to JavaScript, or write a valid Groovy sample.